# Синонимизировать метки [logger] и [логирование]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

- [logger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logger) (22 вопроса) описания нет
- [логирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) (450 вопросов) описание есть

Основная - конечно, [логирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), потому что она на русском и с ней гораздо больше вопросов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
updating post history, 22 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 22 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 16 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'logger': [logger] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 466
tag remapping of [логирование] and [logger] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```